# I cannot understand what I have done wrong here

Tags: python, pygame

Im learning Pygame and I cannot understand how I can possibly screw this up. All I get is a black screen.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game!")

bg = pygame.image.load("graphics/bg.bmp").convert()
chris = pygame.image.load("graphics/chris.bmp").convert_alpha()

x,y=0,0
movex, movey=0,0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=0

    x+=movex
    y+=movey

    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
    screen.blit(chris, (100, 100))

    pygame.display.update
```

All I get from this is a black screen. The bg.bmp is a grey background image and chris is a character with the same background.
This is taken from theNewBostons tutorial. Copied everything.
I have Python 2.7 and Pygame 1.9.2 64bit

Please help :)

Comment: You didn't call `update` on the last line. A lint tool probably would have caught that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
pygame.display.update
```

Should perhaps be:

```
pygame.display.update()
#                    ^^
```

without the parentheses; python looks up the `update` attribute on `display`, but doesn't do anything more; with the parentheses, it then *calls* the attribute it found.